# Datalabels are not shown in 3D Highcharts bar/column

Tags: highcharts

I'm using 3D Column Highcharts and it does not show the datalabels, in 2D is ok but 3D is not. It's also so strange that the png download shows the datalabels.

```
// Set up the chart
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'column',
        options3d: {
            enabled: true,
            alpha: 15,
            beta: 15,
            depth: 50,
            viewDistance: 25
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Chart rotation demo'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Test options by dragging the sliders below'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            depth: 25
        },
    },

   series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true
        }
    }],

});
```

I expect the datalabels can be shown at the top of the columns, need help and thanks a lot!

Comment: It looks like a small Highcharts Bug, already reported on related GitHub page: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/11776

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you noticed it but upgrading to V7.2.1 will fix the issue.

Comment: The answer seems to be very broad. Please explain reasons why upgrading would fix the issue.